# WordPress - Show previewed styles only in Customizer

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to write a WordPress theme that saves my Customizer settings to a separate, static stylesheet so that only a CSS file needs to be served to the user instead of a bunch of `get_theme_mod` requests. I generate this file with the code below:

```
<?php 
    $my_css = '/* Styles with get_theme_mod() fetched here */';

    $customize_css = fopen(get_template_directory() . '/assets/styles/customize.css', 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");

    // Write static CSS file
    fwrite($customize_css, $my_css);
    fclose($customize_css);

?>
```

However, I still need to set it up so that I can live preview my settings when using the Customizer, and I'm not sure how to approach that. I know I can put the below code in the `<head>`:

```
<style>
   .some-element {
       attribute: <?php echo get_theme_mod('my_theme_setting'); ?>
   }
</style>
```

But I'm not sure how to/if I can load this only when viewing a Customizer preview. I can't find in the WP documentation if there's something similar to, say, `is_admin_bar_showing` for the Customizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately found the answer:

```
<?php is_customize_preview(); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_customize_preview